# PHP Redirect with data session destroys

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to have a formular with `header("location")`.

And it workes just fine except one thing. When im trying to set the session that is holding the message it sets the session but when im trying to write it out, the problems starting..

Its like he go inside the if then delete the cookie, jumps out of the if and trys to get there again..

Here is my code:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['sess_error'])) { 
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">';
    foreach ($_SESSION['sess_error'] as $val) { 
        echo $val.'<br>'; 
    }
    unset($_SESSION['sess_error']);
}

if (empty($_POST['username'])) { $error[] = 'Du måste fylla i ett användarnamn...'; }    
if (empty($_POST['password'])) { $error[] = 'Du måste fylla i ett lösenord...'; }
elseif ($sql->num_rows == 0) { $error[] = 'Något fel uppstog, du kunde inte bli inloggad...'; }
if (count($error) > 0) { 
    $_SESSION['sess_error'] = $error;
}
```

Anyone got any idea why this is happening and what can I do to prevent it?

The whole script:

```
<?php
SESSION_START();
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) { 
            $error = null;
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."' LIMIT 1");
            if (empty($_POST['username'])) { $error[] = 'Du måste fylla i ett användarnamn...'; }
            if (empty($_POST['password'])) { $error[] = 'Du måste fylla i ett lösenord...'; }
            elseif ($sql->num_rows == 0) { $error[] = 'Något fel uppstog, du kunde inte bli inloggad...'; }
                if (count($error) > 0) { 
                    $_SESSION['sess_error'] = $error;
                }
                else { 
                    while ($r = $sql->fetch_array()) { 
                        $_SESSION['sess_username'] = $r['username']; 
                        $_SESSION['sess_userID'] = $r['userID'];
                        $_SESSION['sess_admin'] = $r['admin']; 
                        $_SESSION['sess_logg'] = 1;
                    }
                }
                header("Location: ./");
            }
?>
```

Comment: When do you use redirection? Please add redirection part also

Comment: I think you are showing the error before redirecting. And when the page gets redirected the session is being unset and the message is not shown in the redirected page

Comment: Are you building a form validation? If so, stay on the same page and add these errors to the form fields.

Comment: Have you put `session_start()` on top of page? Or alternatively, you can `session.auto_start = 1` in `php.ini`

Comment: Yes i got the session_start on top of the page.

Comment: Where is the cookie delete part, session_destroy() part...

Comment: unset($_SESSION['sess_error']) - Do you mean that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the whole problem, i just had to add an exit; after the header(""); and it worked just fine!

Answer (score -1):

There might be a missing start_session() on the page where you want to set the form errors, after the redirection.

File: "login.php":

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    var_dump($_SESSION);

    if(isset($_SESSION['session_logg']) && $_SESSION['session_logg'] === '1') { 
        echo 'Logged in :' . $_SESSION['session_username'];
    } elseif (isset($_SESSION['sess_error'])) { 
        var_dump($_SESSION['sess_error']);
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">';
        foreach ($_SESSION['sess_error'] as $val) { 
            echo $val.'<br>'; 
        }
        echo '</div>';

        unset($_SESSION['sess_error']);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['login'])) { 
                $error = array();
                $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : false;
                $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : false;

                // no username or password given
                if ($username === false or $password === false) 
                { 
                    $_SESSION['sess_error'][] = 'Login Error.';
                    header("Location: login.php");
                    exit();
                }

                // username, pw given, lets ask db for that guy
                $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."' LIMIT 1");

                // user not found in db, goodbye
                if ($sql->num_rows == 0) { 
                    $_SESSION['sess_error'][] = 'Något fel uppstog, du kunde inte bli inloggad...';       
                    header("Location: login.php");
                    exit();
                }

                // user found
                else { 
                    $r = $sql->fetch_array()) { 
                    $_SESSION['sess_username'] = $r['username']; 
                    $_SESSION['sess_userID'] = $r['userID'];
                    $_SESSION['sess_admin'] = $r['admin']; 
                    $_SESSION['sess_logg'] = 1;
                    header("Location: index.php");
                    exit();                            
                }                      

     }
    ?>
```

side note: not releated to your problem: never show the correct error on login.
say: "login failed", instead of "username xy" not found.

Comment: It is session_start()

Comment: The session_start is on the top of the page. Should i maybe post that too?

Comment: Yes! It's a key part of your question.